# Shorten if function used in multidimensional array

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I understand that min= uses shorten if function, however can someone explain me how does it count in order? As I get a bit lost with these multidimensional arrays :S.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main ()
{
  int i, z, m = 3, n = 4;

  int min, max, mid, min_i, max_i;

  int A[m][n];

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
      for (z = 0; z < n; z++)
        {
          scanf ("%d", &A[i][z]);
        }
    }

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      min = A[A[min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]][i] < A[2][i] ? min_i : 2][i];
      max = A[A[max_i = A[0][i] < A[1][i]][i] > A[2][i] ? max_i : 2][i];
      mid = A[0][i] + A[1][i] + A[2][i] - max - min;
      A[0][i] = min;
      A[1][i] = mid;
      A[2][i] = max;
    }

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
      printf ("\n");
      for (z = 0; z < n; z++)
        {
          printf ("%d ", A[i][z]);
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't write convoluted, confusing code like that.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "count in order"?

Comment: This is a so difficult code to debug and maintain.

Comment: It counts also max and then middle. but I deleted them because that's the place which gets me confusing.

Comment: I've added full code if its gonna be more understandable, what I need is only to understand how does min work, as I can interpret it also with max function..

Comment: Look up the C operator precedence rules, and add parentheses around the sub-expressions with higher precedence. Then work your way from the inside out, to determine how it's calculating.

Comment: The full code isn't more or less understandable, since it's just more of the same stuff. You should learn how to interpret expressions based on the underlying principles, not get someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @Barmar if you don't understand what does it do then dont teach me how to get information, I asked you one thing how does it work and if you can't tell then its not my fault that I can't ask others to give me a brief information...

Comment: Give a man a fish, he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider how the minimum is calculated. Expression

```
min = A[A[min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]][i] < A[2][i] ? min_i : 2][i];
```

can be rewritten like

```
min = 
      A[
         A[
            min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]
          ][i] < A[2][i] ? min_i : 2
       ][i];
```

The most inner expression is

```
min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]
```

If `A[0][i] > A[1][i]` then `min_i` will be equal to 1. Otherwise it will be equal to 0.
Thus after evaluation this expression `min_i` will be equal to the index of the row (either row 0 or row 1) with the minimum value.

You could substitute this one statement for the following sequence of statements

```
min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i];

min = A[min_i][i] < A[2][i] ? A[min_i][i] : A[2][i];
```

The same way there is calculated `max`.

You could write this loop more clear using the ternary operator

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    min = A[1][i] < A[0][i] ? A[1][i] : A[0][i];
    min = min < A[2][i] ? min : A[2][i];

    max = A[0][i] < A[1][i] ? A[1][i] : A[0][i];
    max = A[2][i] < max ? max : A[2][i];

    mid = A[0][i] + A[1][i] + A[2][i] - max - min;

    A[0][i] = min;
    A[1][i] = mid;
    A[2][i] = max;
}
```

Or

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    min = A[0][i];
    if ( A[1][i] < min ) min = A[1][i];
    if ( A[2][i] <= min ) min = A[2][i];


    max = A[0][i];
    if ( max < A[1][i] ) max = A[1][i];
    if ( max <= A[2][i] ) max = A[2][i];     

    mid = A[0][i] + A[1][i] + A[2][i] - max - min;

    A[0][i] = min;
    A[1][i] = mid;
    A[2][i] = max;
}
```

An elegant code could be written using C++. For example the loop could look like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    auto min_max = std::minmax( { a[0][i], a[1][i], a[2][i] } );

    a[1][i] = a[0][i] + a[1][i] + a[2][i] - min_max.first - min_max.second;
    a[0][i] = min_max.first;
    a[2][i] = min_max.second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
min = A[A[min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]][i] < A[2][i] ? min_i : 2][i];
```

Let's examine the expression from inside out:

```
          min_i = A[0][i] > A[1][i]
```

The result of the comparison is either `0` or `1`. If `A[0][i]` is larger than `A[1][i]` the result is `1`. Otherwise it is `0`. The next part of the expression is:

```
        A[      /* 0 or 1 */       ][i]
```

This selects `A[0][i]` if the result above was `0`, and `A[1][i]` if it was `1`. In other words, it selects the smaller of the two elements. Next expression:

```
        A[      /* 0 or 1 */       ][i] < A[2][i]
```

This compares the smaller of the two first elements with `A[2][i]` which is the third element. It results in `0` if `A[2][i]` is smaller, and `1` otherwise. Then:

```
                                  /* 0 or 1 */    ? min_i : 2
```

This results in `min_i` (which was the smaller of the first two elements) if the result above was `1`. Otherwise the result is `2`. And finally:

```
min = A[                     /* min_i or 2 */                ][i];
```

This expression selects whichever element was the smallest of the three.

---

I can not imagine a situation where this produces in better code than the much more readable:

```
min = A[0][i];
if (A[1][i] < min)
  min = A[1][i];
if (A[2][i] < min)
  min = A[2][i];
```